# Web Audio API's AnalyserNode alternative for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fft, audio-analysis

Audio analysis in web browser can be easily performed by [AnalyserNode of Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode).

Is there something similar for Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-audio-api

It's the web audio API for node.js, which sounds like what you're looking for. I haven't used it though, so I can't vouch for how good it is. The web audio API changes periodically, so I don't know how well that library stays in sync with the current spec.

Comment: I know that library. It does not currently implement the AnalyserNode.